# Executing the main method every 2 seconds with original input from user

Tags: c#

I need to make a tree in console which has moving ornaments, these ornaments need to move every 2 seconds.

The tree is made out of X`s and ornaments are O`s, the ornaments are randomly put at different positions and different colors.

The ornaments need to change position and color every 2 seconds.

I need help executing the main method every two seconds with the same initial input from the user.

```
      X
     XXX
    XXXOO
   XXXOOXO
  XXXOOXOXO
 XOXXXOXXXOX
XXXOOOXOOXOXX
     | |
```

Im thinking of just restarting the execution of the main method every two seconds, but when it restarts it uses the input that the user entered the first time. I just dont know how to execute a method every two seconds

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("How many levels high do you want the tree to be :");
            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int treeHeight = input, Space, sX;
            Console.WriteLine("Tree:");
            for (int i = 1; i <= treeHeight; i++)   //Height loop
            {
                for (Space = 1; Space <= (treeHeight - i); Space++)  //space loop
                    Console.Write(" ");
                for (sX = 1; sX <= i; sX++)         //left x loop with random ornaments
                    Console.Write(GetChar(GetRand()));
                for (sX = (i - 1); sX >= 1; sX--)     //right x loop with random ornaments
                    Console.Write(GetChar(GetRand()));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            for (int k = 1; k <= (treeHeight - 2); k++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.Write("| |");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string GetChar(int iRandom)
        {
            string character;
            switch (iRandom)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    character = "O";

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                    character = "O";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    character = "O";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    character = "O";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                    character = "X";
                    break;
            }
            return character;
        }

        static Int32 GetRand()
        {


            Random irandom = new Random();
            int iNum = irandom.Next(0, 11);
            return iNum;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a timer after you take the input from the user:

```
    // called every 3 seconds.
    private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Draw something.... ");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("How many levels high do you want the tree to be :");
        int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int treeHeight = input, Space, sX;
        Console.WriteLine("Tree:");

        // Timer.
        var t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 3000);

        // Prevent the app from closing
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thats essentially what i need but instead of calling that "TimerCallback" method, i need it to execute all my code after the user inputs a value, every 2 seconds.

Comment: I only started using C# today and i`m pretty unsure of how timers work

Comment: You dont need to call it. It's called automatically every X seconds. Just place you code inside the timer.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean ;) thank you